# Error on restoring packages on .net core project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I can't find a way to make work the package restore for my .net core project.
I've just created a new empty project from visual studio.
After the project template is created and it tries to restore the packages I get this error

```
log  : Restoring packages for C:\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\project.json...
Error: Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 1, position 8994.
```

I've tried to install the latest version of .net core 1.1 SDK and Runtime, and also repair the visual studio 2015 installation. But nothing worked.

Edit:

This is the project.json that is created from visual studio

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003133"
  }
}
```

Environment data

```
dotnet --info  output:
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003133)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003133
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  74df06500c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Provide contents of your `project.json` file.

Comment: Ok I'll provide it, thank you